# ref for react-player works on codesandbox but breaks locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, ref, codesandbox

I'm trying to make a player with my own controls, and as I was looking at the demo code for react-player, I saw I had to use ref to play the video from a certain place with a range input. [Documentation here](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player#adding-custom-players)

In the [demo app](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/blob/master/src/demo/App.js), ref is used in this way:

```
  ref = player => {this.player = player}
```

Then it's passed to the ReactPlayer component

```
   <ReactPlayer
       ref={this.ref}
       className='react-player'
          ...
    />
```

When I tried to do the same, it breaks, but as I was putting the code on CodeSandbox to submit it here as a question, I discovered it works perfectly.

Locally, I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'player')" . What can I do to make it work locally just like it works on CodeSandbox? The code is absolutely the same, so I'm scratching my head here.
Edit: Might be because it's using this in something that isn't a Class, but how do I do it in a function then? And why would it work in CodeSandbox?

[Link to CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kalam-26rpxr?file=/src/App.js) / [Link to what I have locally on Github](https://github.com/fcherini/reactplayer/tree/master/src)

Comment: Whatever you doing, I don't think you mean using `this` on function instance, I guess thats what breaks your code. I believe you tried to change code from class to function components.

Comment: @DennisVash yeah, I thought that was the issue, but then it worked on CodeSandbox. How do I do that ref with the player in a function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow React API and use `useRef` hook to handle refs.

```
export default function FullPlayer() {
  const playerRef = useRef();

  const handleSeekMouseUp = (e) => {
    // ...
    playerRef.current.seekTo(parseFloat(e.target.value));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlayer
        ref={playerRef}
        className="react__player"
        url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wp43OdtAAkM"
        playing={state.isPlaying}
        loop={true}
        played={state.played}
        controls={false}
      />
      {/*...*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit purple-shadow-u14kv0]